# Nextcloud trusted domain with auto configuration via environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When i'm configure nextcloud (which run in docker container ) using environment variables , i can't visit site after it and i need to configure manually with connection to docker with bash .
How to solve this problem or make it automatically without creating my own docker image?

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable only gets picked up and applied to the config when building a brand new instance. If you've already created a config.php file which is mapped in that volume, that environment variable will not override it.

If you want to keep your existing config intact, you need to SSH into your NAS and go to your Nextcloud Docker folder and find `/config/config.php`. For me this was located at: `/docker/nextcloud/config/www/nextcloud/config`

Then type: `sudo nano config.php`

Quick vi refresher - i to insert, esc to exit edit mode, and :qw to quit write mode but in this instance you may need to use :qw!

And add a new domain just add new entries by appending a new item to the PHP array:

```
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.0.29',
    1 => 'cloud.example.com',
  ),
```

Reference: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/howto-add-a-new-trusted-domain/26

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an issue with Trusted Domains.
If you have a look at their repository (readme) at https://github.com/nextcloud/docker you will see an environment variabled called NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS which you can set in your docker environment.

Alternatively, you will find it in the {app}/config/config.php
The default values set for it, in my experience, is only 'localhost' to enable connecting to NextCloud from localhost at the very least.

Hope this helps.